# How to run long running fucntion in background without using any external job-queue or message-broker in Express.js api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rabbitmq, background-task

I want to run time consuming function in background when [`express`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) api get called. currently I am doing this using [`RabbitMQ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ).

```js
var rabbitMQ = require('rabbitmq')

var myApi = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        let { city, country } = req.body

        var channel = await rabbitMQ.connection
        var payload = {city, country}
        var result = channel.publish('rabbitMQxchange', 'myQueue', new Buffer(JSON.stringify(payload)), { persistent: true })

        res.json({success: true})
    } catch(error) {
        res.json({success: false, "Some Error"})
    }
}
```

I dony want to use RabbitMQ or other job queue things. So I want to build some approach like this.

```js
function myLongRunningFunction(city, country) {
    
}

var myApi = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        let { city, country } = req.body

        // This should run in background
        myLongRunningFunction(city, country)

        res.json({success: true})
    } catch(error) {
        res.json({success: false, "Some Error"})
    }
}
```

What can be the approach to run function in background?

Comment: You could use the built-in `event` library from Node.js, so you can just simply fire an event, and then your `myLongRunningFunction` function can be a listener to that particular event and start the process.

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei: But when the `EventEmitter` object emits an event, all of the functions attached to that specific event are called synchronously. So can we really use it? or we have to use `setImmediate` in event listener?

Comment: Lets a quick chat over here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250870/74930215