# Unexpected synchronous behaviour when using nodejs events module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, events

I am using Node Events module for executing my function asynchronously.

```js
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

eventEmitter.on('myEvent', f2);

function f1(x, y) {
    console.log('got', x, y)

    eventEmitter.emit('myEvent', x, y);
    eventEmitter.emit('myEvent', x, y);
    eventEmitter.emit('myEvent', x, y);

    console.log('done')
}

var count = 0
function f2(x, y) {
    count++;
    console.log('from f2', x, y, count)
}

f1(1, 2)
```

Its output is

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:~/tmp/test-node$ node alok.js 
got 1 2
from f2 1 2 1
from f2 1 2 2
from f2 1 2 3
done
```

My expected output is

```
got 1 2
done
from f2 1 2 1
from f2 1 2 2
from f2 1 2 3
```

Why `console.log('done')` is running in last. or Why execution is synchronous?

Comment: Because absolutely nothing in your code is asynchronous.

Comment: Then what is use of `eventEmitter.emit()` if that is running in sync?

Comment: To emit events. To allow other code in your app react to them. Think of it like a "messaging service/event bus" (Don't take that too literally). You can make your code with `process.nextTick()` and timers asynchron. But as deceze said, firing events happens synchron. You are responsible for the asynchronous(ity) when you write a function.

Comment: @Marc: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74930215/how-to-run-long-running-fucntion-in-background-without-using-any-external-job-qu ?

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how it works:

> When the `EventEmitter` object emits an event, all of the functions attached to that specific event are called *synchronously*.
>
> [..]
>
> ### Asynchronous vs. synchronous
>
> The `EventEmitter` calls all listeners synchronously in the order in which they were registered. This ensures the proper sequencing of events and helps avoid race conditions and logic errors. When appropriate, listener functions can switch to an asynchronous mode of operation using the `setImmediate()` or `process.nextTick()` methods:
>
> ```
> const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
> myEmitter.on('event', (a, b) => {
>   setImmediate(() => {
>     console.log('this happens asynchronously');
>   });
> });
> myEmitter.emit('event', 'a', 'b');
> ```
>
> https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v19/events